# Common Interface for Dependency Injection

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

I am working on an open source lib which uses Ninject for Dependency Injection purposes. I would like to offer others the ability to use their own injection libs with my code. I do not use anything specific to Ninject as far as I am aware.

Is there a Standard interface already in use by the community that I can use for this purpose? If not has anyone created such an interface before?

Comment: Not sure why someone wants to close it. Seems like a valid question to me.

Comment: I read the intro to questions and it said be specific and check if there was an answer of the same and there wasn't. Not sure why they would want to close either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where the [Common Service Locator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) is designed for. There is a [CSL adapter for Ninject](http://nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator.NinjectAdapter/).